# Is possible to use access control for Azure Synapse Notebooks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, azure-synapse

I need to assign permissions in Azure Synapse environment for notebooks or directories

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible.
Access control is available inside Manage. You can use RBAC for synapse too.